# Streaming video pauses with bluetooth

Tags: video, iphone, ios, bluetooth

I have an iPhone 4S and an LG LBS-700 bluetooth headset which I used to use a lot to watch streaming videos on my phone. I haven't watched any in a while - possibly since before iOS 7, but I'm not sure - and in the last week or so started again, and I'm finding that the video will run for about 5 minutes or so, and then start pausing every 1-3 minutes or so, for about 10-15 seconds each time, before picking up and playing again... a couple of minutes later, another pause, etc.

This does not happen when I am not using the Bluetooth headset. It also does not seem to matter what the source of the streaming video is; I've tried Netflix, Amazon and Plex Media Server; they all exhibit the same behaviour.

Does anybody know why this might be happening, and what can be done about it - aside from "don't use Bluetooth"?

Comment: On iOS 6 your video was running properly, right?

Comment: Yes, definitely, with or without bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like the Bluetooth device is experiencing a firmware issue when trying to communicate with the device running on iOS 7. I'd try either putting fresh install of iOS 7 on your iPhone, or getting in touch with LG. It's most likely an error on their part.